# pip3 install wheel from artifactory gives oserror

Tags: python-3.x, pip, artifactory

I deployed a wheel file to an artifactory repository using the following code:

```
def upload_wheel(artifactory_path: ArtifactoryPath, wheel_path: Path):
    metadata = extract_wheel_metadata(wheel_path)  # get metadata from wheel
    pkg_name = metadata['Name']
#create parent folder
    folder_to_create = artifactory_path / pkg_name / metadata['Version']
    folder_to_create.mkdir(parents=True)

#deploy file
    folder_to_create.deploy_file(wheel_path)

    deployed_file = folder_to_create / wheel_path.name

    add_props(deployed_file, metadata)
```

When I pip install the wheel file (after making changes to the pip.conf file), it shows searching through the repository and gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/filename.whl'
```

Any idea why this is happening? When i place the file in the directory it installs it without any issues. Is it because of the way I am deploying it?

Comment: These scenario might occur when the package was downloaded to Artifactory local cache and then removed/deleted for some reason. Can you try deleting all content (or that specific package) from the remote-repository-cache and perform a zap cache?

Comment: @LakshmiPrasad it's a local repository and I can't perform a zap cache. I deleted the package and reuploaded it using `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r local` but it gives me the same issue.

Comment: @LakshmiPrasad Moreover, pip installing the package works but not the wheel file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by passing the URL to the pip install followed by the whl file.

`pip install URL\filename.whl`

Answer (score 0):

Is artifact getting downloaded from Artifactory? you may see get request with 200 return code from pip client. If possible, post complete pip client output.

Also, you may try '*pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall ----*' by clearing the local pip client cache.